# can't call button id in kotlin file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I have made a button in xml and then assigned an id but can't call the id in  kotlin file because I can't import.kotlin.android......

Also I've seen videos but the gradle solution is no longer working. Please help

I've tried other solutions from youtube and stack overflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.widget.Button
```

you need to import this necessary imports

**OR**

Also you can use binding for call button

View Binding enabled in your module's build.gradle file.

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

In your activity or fragment where you want to access the views:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutBinding // Declare view binding variable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = YourLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Access your views via binding here
    }
    // Other methods and code
}
```

Comment: The android widget button is getting highlighted in grey and also ive turned on the view bindings and as i am new to android studio i dont know where to put the private lateint  code

Comment: I edit my code so you can check.